# Calculate Number of Days under Contract from List of Contracts

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two sheets in an Excel workbook. The first is a list of contracts for workers A, B, and C and the contracted revenue rate per day.

[image]

In the other sheet, I would like to calculate the number of days each worker (A, B, C, etc.) (ignore the Revenues in the image) is under contract during the given period. What formula would I use to do this?

[image]

Comment: Would helper columns be OK?

Comment: sure if it gets the job done

Comment: In Picture 2, did the date is the end of the contract for each stage?

Comment: Picture 2 is a forecast of how many days each worker is under contract during Q2 2019, Q3 2019, Q4 2019, etc. I am trying to answer between June 30, 2019 (exclusive) and September 30, 2019 inclusive how many days A under contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add columns with the period date on the right of your first table. Then under each period's end date, insert the following formula:

```
=MAX(IF($C3>G$2,G$2,$C3)-IF($B3<F$2,F$2,$B3),0)
```

And populate to fill the table

[image]

Then for your second table, use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF($A3:$A6,$A13,G3:G6)
```

[image]

If you want to have the number of days times the rate calculated, use the following formula in the second table:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$3:$A$6=$A13),$D$3:$D$6,G$3:G$6)
```

[image]